# Заменить данные в xml файле из внешнего файла

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl

Всем привет.
Может кто подскажет, возможно ли создать файл **xslt-3** так чтобы данные в xml файле изминялись беря данные из внешнего файла(поиск и замена)?
Например есть xml файл в нем есть переменная **obrabotki1** в которой есть название бумаги которая постоянно миняется и видов много, можно ли сделать так чтобы данные брались из внешнего файла? например: во внешнем файле xml в нем в каждой строке набрано имя бумаги и через тильду на что изменять: ART_150 **~** Art150_320x465, ART_170 **~** Art170_320x465. И так весь список.

**Оригинальный файл в которм нужно изменять переменную**

```
<zakazy>
    <params KodProverki=""
            obrabotki1="ART_150"
            obrabotki1="ART_170"
    />  
</zakazy>
```

**Пример файла в которм нужно искать и встявлять зачения в оригинальный файл**

```
ART_150~Art150_320x465
ART_170~Art170_320x465
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 3.0 представил понятие maps.

Это именно то, что вам нужно.

*$find_and_replace* переменная держит *map*: пары ключ/значение (поиск и замена), сколько их необходимо.

**Исходный XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zakazy>
    <params KodProverki="" obrabotki1Name="Жесткий картон, 350 гр." obrabotki1="KREATO_350_B3"/>
</zakazy>
```

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" expand-text="yes" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:variable name="find_and_replace" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'Жесткий картон, 350 гр.'" select="'Картон 350 гр.'"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'KREATO_350_B3'" select="'Креато 350 гр.'"/>
            <!--Добавьте столько пар ключ/значение, сколько необходимо-->
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@*[.=map:keys($find_and_replace)]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" select="map:get($find_and_replace, .)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Результат**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<zakazy>
  <params KodProverki="" obrabotki1Name="Картон 350 гр." obrabotki1="Креато 350 гр."/>
</zakazy>
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо. Вы очень крутой специалист

Comment: Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за мое предложение в Microsoft: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь, все работает но потребовалось в той же xml еще сделать одну замену. Нужно чтобы еще замену производил в тексте. **Например:** `gotovnost="5 декабря 2022, в 14.54"/>.` Нужно в переменной **gotovnost** вместо слово **декабрь** поставить **цифру месяца (12)** ну и тд. а числа и все остальное осталось. Как это дописать в код который вы мне написали. И реально ли это сделать? **Заранее спасибо**

Comment: Пожалуйста, задайте отдельный новый вопрос.